# What does it mean to have a sixer on the jukebox?

Tags: meaning

I've come across it in the 22nd episode of the 7th episode of *The Office*. Here is the context:

> Deangelo: Listen. **I’ve got a sixer**. “Automatic for the People” **on the jukebox**. Let’s hit the park after sundown. Come on! Pick up some sausage if you want.

I've looked up every word separatey but still can't figure out what he means there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slang term "sixer" usually refers to a six pack of beer.

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sixer)

So the speaker is saying: "I have a six-pack of beer, some good music, let's party!"

The "sixer" is not on the jukebox.  The song "Automatic for the People" is playing on the jukebox.